# Concat ComboBox choices into textbox

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 tables:

1. tbl1Artist:
       ID - (PK),
       ArtistName,
       ArtistSKU
2. tbl1Medium:
       ID - (PK),
       MediumType,
       MediumSKU
3. tbl1Artwork:
       ID - (PK),
       Artist_ID - (FK),
       Medium_ID - (FK),
       PieceName,
       DateCompleted,
       ArtWorkSKU,
       Thumbnail

I want to create a form that has a ComboBox for choosing an Artist and a separate ComboBox for choosing the medium type. There will be a TextBox for inputting the name of the piece and a date picker (ComboBox). I need to concatenate the ArtistSKU based on the choice from the Artist with the MediumSKU based on the choice from the Medium ComboBox, and the first 5 letters of the PieceName from the TextBox.

[image]

I have done some research to try and figure out how to achieve this but with no luck. Can this be achieved inside of Access with queries or is VBA required to achieve the intended outcome?

I am not that familiar with Access and appreciate all the assistance and guidance.

Let me know if you need further information about this request.

Comment: Why are these controls all UNBOUND?

Comment: That was setup just to show an example of what I am trying to do. I am not sure how to setup the Control Source and Row Source properly for the combo boxes.

Comment: Thanks June7. Your answer was accepted and allows me to improve the rest of my project on my own (for the most part, of course I don't know what I don't know yet...lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with expression in query or textbox. Use Left() function to extract first 5 characters.

Example in textbox:
`=[cbxArtist] & [cbxMedium] & Left([tbxPiece],5)`

If the value you want is actually in another column of combobox list, reference that column by its index. Index begins with 0.
`=[cbxArtist] & [cbxMedium].Column(1) & Left([tbxPiece],5)`

If you want to save calculated value to table, that would require code (macro or VBA), however, advise not to save. Saved calculated values can become 'out of sync' with raw data. This value can be calculated when needed. But if you must, then code would be like:
`Me!ArtWorkSKU = Me.tbxArt`
The real trick is figuring out what event to put this code into. Try the form BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: Ok. It is almost there. For the Medium, however, it is displaying the Medium_ID in the text box for ArtWorkSKU instead of the actual MediumSKU. From the Medium table I need it to show the results that are actually in column 2 of the Medium table. How do I specify that column in the concat?

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Please expand on "advise not to save". Creating the ArtWork SKU is one of the main purposes of the form and that data needs to be saved and associated to that particular art piece. What would the VBA code for this look like? Not asking for you to write it, just provide a framework. You have provided great info that I could probably use to fill in the gaps.

Comment: See revised answer again.